# c++: try to understand vector and class

Tags: c++

I am puzzled by the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
 public:
  A(int _a) : a(_a)
  {
    cout << "A(" << a << ") created" << endl;
  }
  ~A()
  {
    cout << "A(" << a << ") deleted" << endl;
  }
  int a;
};

void test()
{
  vector<A> as;
  A a1(1);
  A a2(2);
  as.push_back(a1);
  as.push_back(a2);
  cout << "test ended" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output.

```
A(1) created
A(2) created
A(1) deleted  <== ?
test ended
A(2) deleted
A(1) deleted
A(1) deleted
A(2) deleted
```

Why there is an extra "A(1) deleted"?

I understand there is implicit copy construct when doing push_back. However, my question is why a1 is treated differently than a2?

Comment: The compiler is still generating a copy constructor. So some instances are being created that you aren't seeing.

Comment: Look up the rule of 5, you have moved/copied objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you call the first `vector#push_back` with object A1, it creates a
  copy of your object A1 using a copy constructor.
- When you call the second vector#push_back with object A2, it has to recreate the vector with two objects. So it deletes the A1 object that it has copied, creates another vector and adds new copies of A1 and A2. That's why you see the first delete statement for A1.
- Finally, when your program exits, both the copies of A1 and A2 are deleted and that's why you see two delete statements for A1 and A2 each.

If you create the vector with an initial size of 2 elements, you would see equal number of objects created for both A1 and A2. Just do

`as.reserve(2);`

to create the vector of two objects so that it doesn't have to recreate the vector when the second object is pushed.

Also, if you define your own copy constructor, you will see when exactly the vector#push_back creates a copy of your object:

```
  A(const A &obj) {
      a = obj.a;
      cout << "A(" << a << ") created in copy constructor" << endl;          
  }
```